# Is it possible to add privileges to a primary token?

Tags: windows, security, token

From what I understand you can change the privileges in a primary token in two ways:

- Enable or disable privileges by using the **AdjustTokenPrivileges**
  function.
- Restrict or remove privileges by using the
  **CreateRestrictedToken** function.

I can't find any information regarding adding privileges to a token, is this possible?

Comment: That sounds like a fundamental design flaw. What would the point of a non-administrator token be, if you could just add back `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` ?

Comment: Yes it would be a fundamental security flaw if you could add privileges like `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` and `SeDebugPrivilege` but lets say for example you have removed `SeTimeZonePrivilege` I'm wondering if there is a way of adding it back?

Comment: No.  That would defeat the purpose of `CreateRestrictedToken`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I got here needing to add `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` while having `SE_DEBUG_NAME` (which is the all your base is belong to us privilege). `CreateRestrictedToken` is not in play, and the answer is definitely yes, it's just a matter of how much code it's going to be.